# SSL Enabled site refusing connections

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am attempting to encrypt my site using SSL. I created a self-signed certificate (in the interim) and am attempting to integrate it into my nginx server.

I placed the certificate into the main nginx.conf file, as I have multiple domains (dev and beta).

```
# SSL
ssl_certificate     /srv/ssl/nginx.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/nginx.key;
ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
```

In the `server` block, I have the following:

```
+server {
+   listen 80;
+   server_name dev.DOMAIN.com;
+
+   location / {
+       rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
+   }
+}

server {
+   listen 443 ssl;
    server_name dev.DOMAIN.com;

    access_log /var/www/dev/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/dev/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/dev/public_html;
+   keepalive_timeout   70;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    // [.. A couple other rewrite statements here ..]
}
```

I made the same changes to the `server` block for my beta build, but while it works in the dev build, I am receiving `Connection Refused` errors on the beta build.

I've verified that both dev and beta files are identical (except for the subdomain).

The code on both builds is identical as well. Neither the error log nor the access log show any entries.

I honestly have no idea where to go next...!

Comment: Can you define what "refusing connections" means?  Is the port closed?  Is the SSL connection returning an error?

Comment: Hi @AndrewM., when I try to access the site, Firefox says that a connection cannot be established. When I try to `wget` the site, the message "Connection Refused" is returned. I believe it is an nginx erorr?

Comment: I can't imagine the port would be closed, as both `dev` and `beta` are hosted on the same machine. SSL on the dev build works, while the beta doesn't.

Comment: Working down the OSI stack, is the port open and accessible?  Try telnetting to 443 and see if you're able to establish a connection (note that windows telnet doesn't necessarily open a connection even though it may look open on the console).

Comment: `julian@julian-work:~$ telnet 50.116.54.128 443 \ Trying 50.116.54.128... \ Connected to 50.116.54.128.`

Comment: Can you verify that "dev.DOMAIN.com" and "beta.DOMAIN.com" are indeed the same machine, and that there's nothing forgotten in your /etc/hosts? "Connection refused", when coming from wget, normally means that the port is closed.

Comment: I'm with @AntonisChristofides on this one; connection refused is an issue with connecting, not with SSL.  Make sure you're accessing the machine you think you are, and also try accessing it from another machine (i.e., not localhost).

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'm almost positive (although by this point, perhaps I've gone bug-eyed) that the two are on one machine, since I set up this machine myself. Perhaps I miswrote an IP address, but I'm sure I double checked that as well. They are both on `50.116.54.128`

Comment: I restored the old `server` blocks for beta, and discovered upon `wget` that it resolved to its CloudFlare DNS IP. *headdesk*. This must be why. My dev builds bypass the CloudFlare network completely.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The answer pertains specifically to my issue. If you are experiencing a similar problem, please read the comments for the original question, as they are probably more relevant**

As it turned out, CloudFlare interferes with SSL websites unless they are specifically configured to be as such. For my case, the `dev` subdomain was set to bypass the CloudFlare network completely, while `beta` was "accelerated", which caused the IP to shift to CloudFlare's IP.

Cloudflare does offer SSL support for the free accounts if you create a subdomain named "ssl". Further support requires the pro version (~$20/mo).